# Getting Incoming Phone Numbers

Tags: telephony, modem

Is it possible with some hardware to get the incoming calls and phone numbers from an ADSL line (in a windows application) ?

I guess I need a driver program of a specific hardware doing this but I don't even know any term to make a search about this.

Comment: "Modem" would be a good start.

Comment: is it possible with just modem ?

Comment: For quite some time, it seems... http://www.talkingcallerid.com/CallerIDCapable.htm

Comment: Think question should be moved to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony?referrer=s2GigkBNnqYlaRLwFFF1-A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [USRobotics modem](http://www.usr.com/products/modem/modem-product.asp?sku=usr5637) for this.